# PHP Code for Connect to MySQL via SSH using phpseclib

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ssh, phpseclib

I want connect to MySQL on server, but the server only can be access with SSH.
I use phpseclib to connect with SSH. And it was successfull.
But when try connect to MySQL it said : Access Denied. 
So, I have these code. Anyone please help me..

```
<?php

//data for connection to SSH
//host : 10.81.229.31
//user : root
//pass : abcde

//here's data for connection to MySQL
//host = 10.81.229.31
//username = root
//password = abcde
//database name = testing


include('Net/SSH2.php');

//connecting to server with SSH
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.81.229.31');

if (!$ssh->login('root', 'abcde')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}else{
    echo "Login Success";
}

//connecting to MySQL
echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h 10.81.229.31 -u root -p testing');

?>
```

Comment: Try login to the server using ssh and then try connect to mysql and see if this works.

Comment: what was the full MySQL error code? Also if this is a remote database, MySQL has to have permission to be accessed remotely.

Comment: @PanamaJack : no error, but it still loading for long time. And still no result.

When this code deleted : 
echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h 10.81.229.31 -u root -p testing');
It will show message : Login Success.

How to know MySQL on server have permission to be accessed remotely ? I have try using 'PUTTY' and it's successfull...

Comment: Did you tried exactly the same command in putty?

Comment: @MarcelBalzer : I use this command 'mysql -h localhost -u root -p testing'

but when I use it, with php code, it's not work...

Comment: OK, and this works when you connected with PUTTY but not with PHP?

Comment: @MarcelBalzer : yes..

Comment: I think i found the problem..
When using PUTTY, after that command we require to enter password..
When using PHP, after that command, I don't know how to enter the password...

Anyone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without a space. eg.

```
echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -ptesting');
```

Quoting from "man mysql":

> --password[=password], -p[password]

Comment: thankyou very much... it's correct..

Succes login to mySQL
I'll post the right code.

Answer (score 1):

When you are ssh'd inside of the box you should reference the database as localhost

```
echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -ptesting');
```

Comment: the command : 'mysql -h localhost -u root -p testing'
it's work with PUTTY, but why it's not work from php code..
I'm so confused ^_^

Comment: You can also try not including -h argument

Comment: still not work..
may I ask you, do you know how to use code $ssh->write() ?
can you give me example.. thanks before

Comment: You'd have to do \n after the command to use it with `$ssh->write()`. But that's not the only issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//data for connection to SSH
//host : 10.81.229.31
//user : root
//pass : abcde

//here's data for connection to MySQL
//host = 10.81.229.31
//username = root
//password = abcde
//database name = testing


include('Net/SSH2.php');

//connecting to server with SSH
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.81.229.31');

if (!$ssh->login('root', 'abcde')) {
    exit('Login to Server Failed');
}else{
    echo "Login to Server Success";
}

//connecting to MySQL
if (!$ssh->exec('mysql -u root -ptesting \r\n')){
    exit('Login to MySQL Failed');
}else{
    echo "Login to MySQL Success";
}

?>
```

\r\n is use for ENTER
And the result :

```
Login to Server SuccessLogin to MySQL Success
```

Thankyou verymuch for everyone, who already help me..

Comment: You only need the \r\n if you're doing `$ssh->write` ;) Otherwise, looks good!